# Storing TextBox input to an array

Tags: c#, arrays, class

Forgive me since I'm a beginner in C# and Programming in general. I'm creating a basic form application (gui) to store data given by the user into some TextBoxes after clicking a button, (Name, surname etc). And I'm having trouble to store these information to an array. Note that the information are in a different Class. 
                                               Sincerely,a programming beginner.

namespace Employees
{
    class Employee
    {
        public int employeeID;
        public string firstname;
        public string lastname;
        public double salary;

```
    public Employee(int IDValue, string firstNameValue,
                     string lastNameValue, double salaryValue)
    {
        employeeID = IDValue;
        firstname = firstNameValue;
        lastname = lastNameValue;
        salary = salaryValue;
    }

    public int EmployeeID
    {
        get
        {
            return employeeID;
        }

        set
        {
            employeeID = value;
        }


    }

    public string FirstName
    {
        get
        {
            return firstname;
        }

        set
        {
            firstname = value;
        }


    }

    public string LastName
    {
        get
        {
            return lastname;
        }

        set
        {
            lastname = value;
        }


    }

    public double Salary
    {
        get
        {
            return salary;
        }

        set
        {
            salary = value;
        }


    }

    public string employeeToString()
    {
        return (Convert.ToString(employeeID) + " " + firstname +
                " " + lastname + " " + Convert.ToString(salary));
    }

}
```

}

Comment: please post the code that is giving you an error or that you do not understand

Comment: I do not understand how to store the information given, to an array, via clicking the button.

Comment: Hi, welcome to SO. If you have written code for this that you can't get to work, then you have come to the right place. Just **[edit your question](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/49592332/edit)** and add the relevant parts of your code into it, because without that we cannot help. Also please see **[ask]**.

Comment: The thing is that I don't want to show the information entered in a rich text box, or a message box for example, but only store them in an array

Answer (score 0):

It could be something like:

```
         private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (textBox1.Text.Length > 0)
        {
            label1.Text = string.Empty;
            string[] arr = textBox1.Text.Split(new string[] { " " }, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);
            for (int i = 0; i < arr.Length; i++)
                label1.Text += arr[i] + "\r\n";
        }
    }
```

Comment: Will this help me store the TextBox input in an array? Thank you.